# Is there a more efficient way to parse this XML using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

```
function xmlParser(xml, projectName) {

var currentIndex = 0;

$(xml).find('entry').each(function(){

    if($(this).attr('projectName').toLowerCase() == projectName) {

        $previous = $(xml).find('entry')[currentIndex - 1]);
        $project = $(this);
        $next = $(xml).find('entry')[currentIndex + 1]);

        //do something with these objects..

    }
    currentIndex++;

});
}
```

Here is some sample code. I have an XML file full of 'entry' elements. Each element has a 'projectName' attribute.

The code basically scans the XML for a project name, like say "Magic Giraffes", returns the XML element matching it, and also the previous & next projects. It works... but I want to know if it's the most efficient way to do it.

See how I'm handling the $previous and $next parts? It's calling the .find() function two more times, and then grabbing elements based on the (-1) and (+1) of the current index. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You should start using variables.. like `var $entries = $(xml).find('entry')` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that each "entry" are siblings, without other elements inbetween:

```
$project = $(this);
$previous = $project.prev();
$next = $project.next();
```

else

```
$project = $(this);
$previous = $project.prev('entry');
$next = $project.next('entry');
```

in order to completly "optimize" your code, you can use variable as often as you can:

```
function xmlParser(xml, projectName) {

var exp = new regexp(projectName, "gi"); 
var $entries = $('entry', xml).filter(function() {
    return exp.test( $(this).attr('projectName'));
});

$entries.each(function(){
    $project = $(this);
    $previous = $this.prev();
    $next = $this.next();

    //do something with these objects..

    });    
}
```

here the "$entries" variable prevent useless access to the full document, "$this" some parsing/selecting by jquery(but that effect is limited on performance).

edit: I did change the looping / matching method, with the help of the "filter" method. Note: if you are certain there is only one "projectname" in entries, you can get rid of the the "$.each" layer, as then "$entries" becomes "$project" directly

Comment: Can you explain the filter? Is this even faster, and if so, could you explain why? Just curious!

Comment: filter is explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). It should be a faster as there are less elements to loop on with "$.each". On the other side your "if" statement might be slightly faster than my regexp. Time difference is tiny anyway. The best way to know is to try both version and use "console.time" and "console.timeEnd" in your code.

Comment: Finally, if you can get rid of the case issue, you could search projectname directly in the selector (`$entries = $('entry[projectName="'+projectName+'"]', xml);`), which is definitvly faster

Comment: Ah awesome, I'll definitely try and solve the casing issue then.

Comment: This solution shaved a solid 4ms off my overall (actual) function. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using entry[projectName=...] selector, and have jquery search for the right entry (see: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ ) however you could have problems with case sensitivity.

When you need the next project, you could use $project.next() (see : http://api.jquery.com/next/ ), same for previous.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the find function you can use the prev() and next() functions. Try this out:

```
$previous = $(this).prev();
$project = $(this);
$next = $(this).next();
```

You can also pass a selector to those to make sure it only returns the prev/next you want like this:

```
.prev('entry');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about efficiency, you can try something like this.  Once you get a list of 'entry' elements, there's no need to keep searching for them again - everything you need is in the array.

```
function xmlParser(xml, projectName) {

    var entries = $(xml).find('entry');
    var previous;
    var project;
    var next;

    $.each(entries, function(index, element)) {
        if (element.attr('projectName').toLowerCase() == projectName) {
            if (index > 0) {
                previous = entries[index - 1];
            } else {
                previous = null;
            }
            project = entries[index];
            if (index < entries.length - 1) {
                next = entries[index + 1];
            } else {
                next = null;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, will definitely avoid recalling .find functions!